# How to change tiny mce image source from remote web server to local server directory

Tags: html, flask, tinymce

I am currently using TinyMCE text editor and flask to setup my website, I would like to ask a few questions:

1. In the tinymce text editor, I have texts and multiple images (the images is from pictures on the internet) and I would like the images to be uploaded and saved to my local server, how to do this?

```
img class="img-responsive" style="box-sizing: border-box; border: 0px; vertical-align: middle; display: block; max-width: 100%; height: 421px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://website.com/location/images.jpg" width="561" /
```

2. I have already saved the text from tinymce to my local server directory and the image source specified is in URL format, I would like to show up the text and images in another website but the images source should be from the one I have downloaded, how to automatically change each of the images source to be from my local server directory?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I think that will be not a right choice as the images are already on web so you don't need to save into your local server directory, If you want to store you can make a upload button where user can upload images from there local machine and you can save it into your local server.

Comment: but it seems because the image source website itself sometime have an error, it also causes error on my side, which the image cannot be displayed